# My web is not sending email verification via Firebase but my then function or error functions not triggering

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on html and java script project but when i try `sendSignInLinkToEmail` its not sending the email and both `then` and `catch` are not triggering

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const database = getDatabase(app);
const auth = getAuth();


var attachment = document.getElementById('attachment');

attachment.onchange = () => {
const selectedFile = attachment.files[0];
}
register.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname-field").value;
  var lname = document.getElementById("lname-field").value;
  var birthdate = document.getElementById("birthdate-field").value;
  var passport = document.getElementById("passport-field").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email-field").value;
  var areacode = document.getElementById("country-select").value;
  var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phonenumber-field").value;
  var country = document.getElementById("country-field");
  var nation = document.getElementById("nation-field").value;
  var emergencyname = document.getElementById("emergencyname-field").value;
  var emergencyrelation = document.getElementById("emergencyrelation-field").value;
  var emergencyinfo = document.getElementById("emergencyinfo-field").value;
  var attachment = document.getElementById('attachment');
  var persentage = document.getElementById('persentage');

  


    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, nation)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in 
            const user = userCredential.user;

            set(ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid), {
              FirstName: fname,
              LastName: lname,
              Birthdate: birthdate,
              PassportNumber: passport,
              Email: email,
              PhoneNumber: phoneNumber,
              Country: country,
              Nationality: nation,
              EmergencyName: emergencyname,
              EmergencyRelation: emergencyrelation,
              EmergencyInfo: emergencyinfo
            });

            async function UploadAttachment() {
              var selectedFile = attachment.files[0];
              var fileName = user.uid
          
              const metaData = {
                contentType: selectedFile.type
              }
          
              const storage = getStorage();
              const storageRef = sRef(storage, "attachments/" + fileName)
          
              const UploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, selectedFile, metaData);
          
              UploadTask.on('state-changed', (snapshot) => {
                var uploadProgress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                persentage.innerHTML = "Upload" + uploadProgress + "%";
              },(error) => {
                alert('error: Image Not Uploaded')
              },
              ()=>{
                getDownloadURL(UploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadUrl) => {
                  console.log(downloadUrl);
                })
              }
              );
            }

            UploadAttachment();

            
            // ...
            console.log("usersigned up");
            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            // ..
            alert(errorMessage);
        });

        const actionCodeSettings = {
          // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
          // URL must be in the authorized domains list in the Firebase Console.
    
          // This must be true.
          handleCodeInApp: true,
          
        };

        sendSignInLinkToEmail(auth, email, actionCodeSettings)
          .then(() => {
            // The link was successfully sent. Inform the user.
            // Save the email locally so you don't need to ask the user for it again
            // if they open the link on the same device.
            console.log("Email Sent");
            window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', email);
            // ...
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            // ...
          }
          );
});
```

Comment: Someone asked this yesterday - wonder if they got an answer - no, they didn't - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71463662/i-am-using-firebase-signinwithemailandpassword-to-login-the-user-was-able-to

Comment: mine doesnt even send the email

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to add `actionCodeSettings` parameter to `sendSignInLinkToEmail`

If not try to

- Use devtools breakpoints
- Check network tab if there is any requests are going to server

Comment: i actually tried it both ways i have `actioncodesettings` in `sendsigninlinktoemail`  and the sign up process is working properly so the network is fine

Comment: I am not talking about internet connection. When you execute `sendSignInLinkToEmail` method it should send a request to server check it's status.

Comment: how do i check that

Comment: when i didnt put a `const actioncodesetting` the server was replying with `actioncodesetting not defined` but now there is nothign

Comment: What is the status code it responses with?

Comment: let me run it agian

Comment: there is no status code `actionCodeSettings is not defined` this is what i get as an alert

Comment: Please share error log